# Create file template with generic macro

Tags: resharper

[image]this is my template code:

```
 using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using Nethos.Ferramentas.AtributosValidacao.Numeros;
using Nethos.Ferramentas.AtributosValidacao.Textos;

$HEADER$namespace $NAMESPACE$
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Classe responsável pela persistência dos dados.
    /// Tabela:  $CLASS$s (PK: Id)
    /// </summary>

    [DataContract]
    [KnownType(typeof(NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericBag< $CLASS$ >))]
    [KnownType(typeof(NHibernate.Collection.PersistentBag))]
    [Serializable]

    public class  $CLASS$
    {           
        $END$
    }
}
```

but in the line "[KnownType(typeof(NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericBag< $CLASS$ >))]" not appear name of the class, just the letter "a"... what's the problem with my code template?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is an issue that the original 8.0 release of ReSharper has with certain plugins, under certain conditions. If you open Visual Studio by double clicking a solution file, the plugin would get initialised too late, and cause exceptions (you can verify by running "devenv.exe /ReSharper.Internal" and look for exceptions). The exceptions can interfere with various parts of ReSharper, unfortunately, macros is one that I've seen.

This has been fixed with ReSharper 8.0.1. Please can you update and try again?